# Managing different Rails versions in different git branches with RVM

Tags: git, rvm, bundler

I'm working on a project that runs on Rails `~> 3.0` on the `master` branch, and `~> 3.1` on another branch.

Obviously those 2 branches need different gemsets.

Do you know of a convenient way of handling the situation using RVM?

I've thought of a couple options, none of them optimal:

- **using `gemset`s** I would have to remember to manually switch `gemset` after each `git checkout`
- **using `bundle package`** I would have to track the `vendor/bundle` directory
- a mix of the two approaches is not even possible, since `.bundle/config` is not tracked
- I could write a `git` `post-checkout` hook, but it sounds a bit hacky (hardcoded branch names and all that)

Is there a better way that I'm failing to think of?

Comment: I know this questions is a bit old. But I've finally gotten around to jot down the steps I use, to deal with different RVM gemsets for git branches. Maybe it could help those who stumbles on this. http://is.gd/pao3ZZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following `git post-checkout` script.
In the `master` branch, I was using gems installed in `$GEM_HOME`. In the other branches, gems were installed locally to `vendor/cache`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#set -x

git_rev() {
  ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null) || return
  echo ${ref#refs/heads/}
}

ref=$(git_rev)

case $ref in
  master)
    echo "removing .bundle/config"
    mv .bundle/config .bundle/config.no
    ;;
  *)
    if [ -f .bundle/config.no ] ; then
      echo "using vendor/cache"
      mv .bundle/config.no .bundle/config
    fi
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: This would make a great comment.  As an answer it fails to provide enough detail to help the next person who stumbles across the question.  Care to provide any additional detail?

Answer (score 2):

You will no longer have to do that when you change into a project directory. RVM 1.8.1 had this reenabled by default. (I've added documentation regarding that to the site and to rvm notes)

However, since this is an in-directory rvmrc change, and the change in the .rvmrc is not picked up, you can force it by doing an 'rvm reload'. The change *should* be picked up, but if its not then do the reload.

Please post any issues you have after doing this to https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Thank you,

Deryl R. Doucette

**NOTE:** After talking with Wayne, he passed on to me via IRC that he would recommend that you do something along the lines of this in your .bash_profile to aid in what you want:

```
  git() { command git "$@" ; [[ -s .rvmrc ]] && . .rvmrc ; }
```

Also, so you understand, RVM does not run as a daemon in any way shape or form. So what you want RVM to do most definintely will **not** be added to RVM. As Wayne said, that would be a fun way to mess with someone's head though! :)

Think of it this way. While admittedly contrived, the action is still the same. What if someone changes the rvmrc under you while you're in the middle of something (another dev working on the dir and doesn't know you are), or some rogue beastie has hacked your system and changes your rvmrc on you thinking he might gain some additional privs somehow by doing so. (This could be in a group controlled project directory where he's obtained access through another user's account, figures out that you are in the same group, changes the rvmrc underneath you to a different ruby+gemset that he's managed to set up through group permissions of the RVM group in a multi-user install, and causes some arbitrary command to be executed. Imagine further, that you **are** in, say, the wheel group and you just finished executing some command for root and the timeout has not completed yet for authorization reduction. Since an rvmrc is really nothing more than a bash script, thats not a far stretch of the imagination. So in the end, that makes for a VERY hazardous environment, not to mention an extremely difficult situation to monitor and control.

Comment: having to remember to `rvm reload` kind of beats the point, as i might as well do a `rvm gemset use` then :)

Comment: well rvm reload is significantly faster to type than rvm gemset use 1.9.2@rails31 so I don't accept that as a valid argument. However, that being said, I will talk with wayne and see what the expected behaviour is for when changes to an .rvmrc in the PWD take place.

Comment: yes, it's faster, but what i meant is that your solution only solves  the simpler part of the problem (saving keystrokes). having to remember to do something after each `git checkout` is the real issue.

Comment: why? you simply use git's hooks like post-commit. Since RVM is not (and never will be) a daemon, people generally use $project_dir/.git/hooks/post-commit to cause these types of actions to take place. While I do realize this is not the **exact** solution that you want, it **is** the proper way to handle it. Please take a read through http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html which covers the hooks. Another one that would be of great assistance is http://goo.gl/Uv1Px

Comment: you're right, it can be set as a hook - hadn't thought of that. anyway, tracking the `.rvmrc` in git looks like a dirty solution to me (the app repo in itself should not be concerned with the developer's local environments) so i'm not too keen on adopting this solution.

Comment: actually Best Practices IS to include the .rvmrc in the repo as it allows other developers to set their environment up to the same specifications are your's. This has been standard practice with RVM controlled projects for as long as there have been .rvmrc files.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an .rvmrc file inside your project directory and add it to the git repo. For one branch, the .rvmrc file would contain a line like

```
rvm 1.9.3-head@rails30 --create
```

for the other branch it would contain

```
rvm 1.9.3-head@rails31 --create
```

That way you'd end up with two gem sets (rails30 and rails31). Also don't forget to activate automatic execution of .rvmrc files in your {home}/.rvmrc (necessary for latest version of rvm, see rvm documentation).

Comment: Just remember to do this on a branch you have no intention of merging into the one with the different rvmrc or it will then overwrite that branch's rvmrc.

Comment: i would prefer not tracking `.rvmrc` files. they represent a local environment and don't belong in a VCS imho.

Answer (score 0):

To follow on morgler's answer, if you have your .rvmrc checked into your git project, you could use git completion to add the git branch name into the .rvmrc gemset name to automate the creation of a gemset for each branch, like:

```
PROJECT_NAME="my_app"
RUBY_VERSION="ruby-1.9.2-p290"
GEMSET_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME}"
# if you have bash completion setup the way I do, you get a gemset for each git branch
if [ -f /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash ]; then
  . /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash;
  GEMSET_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME}-$(__git_ps1 '%s')";
fi
rvm --create "${RUBY_VERSION}@${GEMSET_NAME}"
```

(Note: You'll probably have to modify this. It works for me in OS X, but I was already using [git completion for my terminal prompt](http://stufftohelpyouout.blogspot.com/2010/01/show-name-of-git-branch-in-prompt.html).)

Then cd into the directory and if you do rvm gemset list, you should see that a gemset was created for that git branch. The only hiccup is that after you create a new git branch, you'd need to cd out and in of the directory to get it to recognize the different gemset create in .rvmrc (even though .rvmrc is the same file, it will behave differently).

This is not a perfect solution, and everyone in the project has to be on-board with this. If you put .rvmrc in for one project, you should consider using it for all of them, otherwise just by cd'ing into a directory, the ruby version and gemset could change, and then if you go back to another project that doesn't have an .rvmrc, you might not notice it changed and have trouble.

*Edit: Michal Papis [mentioned](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/817#issuecomment-4442335) that:*

> a possible solution for this would be to use .versions.conf introduced
>   here: https://gist.github.com/1912050#gistcomment-86575 - it should be
>   easy to put there a flag -> ruby-gemset-git-branch which would append
>   branch to gemset name if different then master

Answer (score -2):

Use [rbenv](http://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) instead of RVM. Then you'll manage your gems entirely using Bundler.

Modify your Gemfile so that one branch is for Rails 3, and the other for Rails 3.1.

Then run `bundle exec rails server` when starting WEBrick and bundler will use the version of Rails that the branch you are on needs. Keeps things DRY ;)

Read my short intro to [getting started with rbenv](http://streaming.nfm.id.au/first-thoughts-after-three-weeks-using-rbenv).

Comment: using only bundler to manage gem versions forces you to use `bundle exec ...` which in case of `bundle exec rails server` is quite overhead compared to `r s` (which you can achieve by using my gem http://rubygems.org/gems/rubygems-bundler and `alias r=rails`) ... but still bundler does not provide separation for plugins - like rubygems plugins, you can get them all or none ...

Comment: Citation needed. `rbenv` has binstubs for gems that you install with `gem` rather than bundler, just `gem install` it then you can use `rails s` as per usual. Also, if you're going to alias something, why not alias `bundle exec rails`?

Comment: here is my article going in more details http://niczsoft.com/2011/11/what-you-should-know-about-rbenv-and-rvm/ , and why not to alias r to bundle exec rails - because it only works for rails, you will have to create alias for every binary starting on rake finishing with haml or god

Comment: It's no different to your rails alias - it's specific to the rails binary. If you want a more broad solution, alias `bundle exec`. If you really want gem binaries to be globally accessible, just `gem install` them. With RVM you *have* to have a gemset for every project to achieve what `bundle exec` gives you, which means you end up with N copies of rails, haml, rspec, pg, paperclip, factory_girl...